# Is there any solution to overcome the AllocSpace issues?

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on an app that fetches a PDF file by using **http.get(uri.parse('url of pdf'))**.

Over here I am able to build widgets in order to open pdf but after 4th widget the 5th widget is not functioning and I am getting the following output in my terminal

`W/System  ( 4353): A resource failed to call release.  I/BpBinder( 4353): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor> I/EEE.IEEE_SB_Ap( 4353): Background concurrent copying GC freed 202625(6082KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 56% free, 4637KB/10MB, paused 276us total 158.720ms`

Maybe it is not related to opening pdf in pdf viewer but I think it is the reason not allowing me to open pdf

Comment: Is it showing 5 pdfs in one page?

Comment: No the pdfs are retrieved from firebase and each opens on a new page.
Whatever the number be after every 4th widget the pdf is not opening and **W/System  ( 4353): A resource failed to call release.  I/BpBinder( 4353): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>**
is the frequent output on the terminal.